# Jquery which event handle when add/remove to token input?

Tags: jquery

I am using tokeninput for autocomplete text box.

now i want to show hide div base on token input.

so in which event i could get token input values on add / remove time ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ then they have `add` `remove` callbacks documented in their home page

```
onAdd
A function to call whenever the user adds another token to their selections. defaut: null (demo).
onDelete
A function to call whenever the user removes a token from their selections. default: null (demo).
```

The syntax is

```
    $("#selector").tokenInput("fetch.php", {
         onAdd: function (item) {
             alert("Added " + item.name);
         },
         onDelete: function (item) {
            alert("Deleted " + item.name);
        }
   });
```

See demo here search for onAdd onDelete http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#onadd-ondelete

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation it has `onAdd` callback which will be invoked whenever user inputs any new token.

From the docs:

> Callbacks
>
> - onResult
>
>   A function to call whenever we receive results back from the server. You can use this function to pre-process results from
>     the server before they are displayed to the user.  default: null
>     (demo).
> - onAdd
>
>   A function to call whenever the user adds another token to their selections. defaut: null (demo).
> - onDelete
>
>   A function to call whenever the user removes a token from their selections. default: null (demo).
> - onReady
>
>   A function to call after initialization is done and the tokeninput is ready to use. default: null

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the functions up front to avoid doing it in the loop:

```
var addFunction = function (item) {
    .... 
};

var deleteFunction = function (item) {
    ....
};

this.$("#mySelector").tokenInput("/ABC/GetMethod", {
    preventDuplicates: true,
    theme: "facebook",    
    queryParam: "term",
    tokenLimit: 1,
    onAdd: addFunction,
    onDelete: deleteFunction
});
```